# How to properly use Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate so my question could be seen as a very straight forward one, also I will try not to be too generic (as I am always told off because of that), although as with all architectural question it is hard to avoid that... I never know where to ask these questions.

I have setup a webapp using Spring + Hibernate. My architecture uses a series of Controllers which make use of Services that ultimately call DAO methods to obtain my domain objects.

I also have a GenericDAO which implements all the basic data access methods (findAll, findById, save, delete, update...) which I extend for my concrete Dao so I only have to implement specific data access methods.

So a request to view all users will have this flow: the proper controller is called through request mapping, which feeds the view with the result from calling `userService.getAllUsers()` which at the same time makes a call to `userDao.findAll()`.

This is all nice and I think I'm doing it properly enough.

My question relates to relationships among domain objects, so let's say users have accounts and for one view I want to show the user's details plus his list of accounts.

I never found out what's the best way to gather the accounts object list. Should I mark the relationship as Eager? Should I make a call like this:

```
user.accountList = accountService.findAccountsByUser(userId);
```

if that's the case then what's the point of specifying the relationship in the first place? Or maybe I am missing some other way here?

What happens with Many to Many relationships? Am I forced to create a domain object called UserAccount (assuming an account can be associated to several users) that maps the relations between the two?

Comment: It's not clear to me what purpose, if any, a "GenericDAO" serves here, as all of these methods you list (and more) are already supported by the `ISession`. There's a case to be made for strongly-typed repositories (testability) but isn't your "DAO" pretty much a useless wrapper around the session? ORMs *replace* DAOs. And it seems a lot of your concerns are essentially around the limitations imposed by this unnecessary layer in between.

Comment: I would like to see an example of what you say working against ISession. Can you provide me with any?

Comment: @Aaronaught - the main reason to wrap the Hibernate session in a repository or DAO abstraction is to avoid coupling your code to Hibernate.

Comment: @MikePartridge: That's not really an answer, because you haven't defined "your code". Clearly the *implementation* of this "DAO" is coupled to Hibernate, so some of "your code" is still coupled. Your comment presupposes that whatever *references* the "DAO" has some compelling reason to be decoupled from Hibernate. But does it? Like I said, repositories aren't that bad because they encapsulate aggregate roots, but his "DAO" doesn't do anything that a session doesn't also do, other than severely limiting the options available to a consumer.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I was referring to the idea that a business logic layer should be decoupled from the persistence layer, i.e. the dependency inversion principle. Using a DAO as an abstraction over the ORM allows you to change which you use without affecting your business logic. This may be overkill, but I don't know the OP's situation.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with dependency inversion? You can inject a session just as easily as injecting a dumb wrapper around the session. Whether a "business logic layer" uses a session object or a wrapper around the session object, it's still coupled to the "persistence layer". Layered architectures are so Y2K anyway, but if you *have* a persistence layer then *something* needs to be coupled to it.

Comment: Well I do have a need for that abstraction, my webapp needed to switch between REST webservices and direct database access so I created a DAO interface, implemented it both with Hibernate and REST JSON scraping and parsing and then I can switch them just as easily without any effects to my service or business logic model layer. But this is a very particular case, I admit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also control the "eager/lazy" fetching at query time. From the docs:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be
>   initialized along with their parent objects using a single select.
>   This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. It
>   effectively overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the
>   mapping file for associations and collections.

I think the more specific question you want to ask here is: how do I avoid loading too many objects (more than necessary for a given situation) but at the same time, when I *do* want to load them all, how do I avoid the dredded [N+1 select issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)

A rule of the thumb can be the following: what's the most often used fashion to get X data for my application? Do I mostly need it with its sub-entities populated or do I only seldom need those as well. This rule should guide you into setting eager/lazy fetching on the association. Then for those non-standard cases where you need data in a fashion different from the declared eager or lazy relationship-level annotation, you can override it using the above mentioned query-level fetch join.

A good way to double check all this is to debug Hibernate at the generated SQL level. For example this can quickly show you if a certain (single) Hibernate query becomes a series of (N+1) selects when getting translated to SQL. Here's a good article on how to configure this:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question and I'm way over my initial doubts, but your question is comprehensive enough, and summarizes what I ended up doing by following "my guts". Have an upvote, sir.

Comment: your *answer is what I meant